# ActiveRecord Objects created in Cucumber not showing in Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using cucumber (cucumber (1.1.0) cucumber-rails (0.3.2)) trying to test the web UI on a rails 2.3.14 application.  The problem is that I am creating the user in the feature step:

```
visit("/")

@admin_user = Factory.create :admin_user
@admin_user.email
@admin_user.update_attributes :password => "testtest", :password_confirmation => "testtest"
@admin_user.register!
@admin_user.activate!

click_link("Login")
fill_in "Email:", :with => @admin_user.email
fill_in "Password:", :with => "testtest"

find("input[type=image]").click
```

But, when I visit the site and try to login the user is not visible in the database.  Calling new_record? on @admin_user returns false but the rails application cannot see it.  Any ideas on why this record is not showing up?  I have confirmed that both cucumber and the rails application are point to the same database.

Comment: Your question is pointless without admin_user code and a code of controller that manages sessions

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear.  when I create the user in the step definition it is not appearing in the database when I try to use capybara to log in with that user.  Also I have tried disabling transactions in the env.rb file `#Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
`  But, that has not seemed to make any difference.  Users I create with in the web application (ie in the control) are there but the admin user I create in the step definition is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ernest said, there are two connections. But turning off transations would slow down your suite, so use this code: https://gist.github.com/470808, and read: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/ especially section 3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they point at the same database? Normally cucumber will run in the test env and you visiting the site will either be in development or production environments.

If you have changed config/database.yml to point the test environment to the development or production database, Cucumber normally wraps each scenario in a transaction which rolls back.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if Cucumber and Rails are using two different connections. For that case, you may need to turn off transactions. More about the topic here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Browsers-and-Transactions